# Help in a calculus question

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to solve this question:

[image]

In item (a)

I know $P'(200)=1/50$ and $P'(250)=8/625$, but how can I know the average rate of $P$ from $200\ in^3$ to $250\ in^3$? Sum and divide by two?

In item (b)

I think it's simple, because $V'=800/P^2$

How can I finish item (a)? the item (b) is correct?

Thanks

Comment: You do not sum and divide by two. The average rate of change is $$\dfrac{1}{b-a}\int_a^b f'(t)dt$$

Comment: Of course, this simplifies...

Comment: @TheChaz2.0 why?

Comment: Could you be more specific? The slope of the line through the points $(a,f(a))$ and $(b,f(b))$ is the average rate of change on the interval $[a,b]$.

Comment: @TheChaz2.0 why the integral? that's my question

Comment: Oh. You can think of it in terms of the [average value of a function](http://www.ugrad.math.ubc.ca/coursedoc/math101/notes/applications/average.html) which is defined as an integral a few lines down on that page. But if the "value" is the rate of change, you are integrating the derivative, and the fundamental theorem of calculus gives us $\dfrac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$

Comment: @TheChaz2.0 thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(To summarize the comments...)*

The average rate of change of a function $f$, from $x = a$ to $x = b$, is $$\dfrac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$$

For part (b), you want $- \dfrac{800}{P^2}$.